# Number of cube roots modulo prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, roots

> Suppose $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$. For $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ show that $f(x)=
>  x^3 - a$ has either $3$ or $0$ roots modulo $p$.

I've tried assuming you only have $1$ root. Then if $n$ is the root you can write $x^3 - a = (x-n)(x^2 + xn + n^2)$. Now I need a contradiction in assuming that quadratic has no root.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Arthur Ive tried assuming you only have 1 root. Then if $n$ is the root you can write $x^3 - a = (x-n)(x^2 + xn + n^2)$. Now I need a contradiction in assuming that quadratic has no root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track. Suppose there is at least one root, $n$. As you have noted, there is a factorization $x^3 - a = (x-n)(x^2 + xn + n^2)$. Now, to see that the quadratic has a root, you need to show that the discriminant $(-3n^2)$ is a square modulo $p$, or equivalently that $-3$ is a square modulo $p$. And remember, you need to use the mod $3$ condition. Does quadratic reciprocity ring a bell?

Comment: Thanks! I got it!